# Setting up a TextSpinner Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, adapter

I'm attempting to set up a TextAdapter for a String array. Basically it's a drop-down menu that holds a list of strings associated with the size of the item that the user wants to purchase.

```
private void SetupSpinner(String[] drawables) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sizes);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, drawables));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String[] drawables;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] drawables) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        this.drawables = drawables;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView view = new TextView(getContext());
        view.setText(Integer.parseInt(drawables[position]));

        return view;
    }
}
```

I had it working with drawables but that's inefficient. I don't want to make graphics for each of the size options. Anyway, all help greatly appreciated!

Comment: please explain your problem clearly. cannot understand what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: I just want a drop-down menu that holds an array of Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a xml custom_spinner

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_main_seen"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/sub_text_seen"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView" />
```

Then put the  spinner in your main xml where you need

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_show"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Then in your class

```
public class SpinnerCustomizationActivity extends Activity {

String[] spinnerValues = { "Blur", "NFS", "Burnout","GTA IV", "Racing", }; 
String[] spinnerSubs = { "Ultimate Game", "Need for Speed", "Ulimate   Racing", "Rockstar Games", "Thunder Bolt" };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_show);     
mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner,    spinnerValues)); }

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects)
{ 
  super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects); }
 @Override 
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) { return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt); }

  @Override
  public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt)

 { 

  return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
 }
  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)       
  { 

 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);                 
 TextView main_text = (TextView)mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen); 
 main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);
 TextView subSpinner = (TextView)mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.sub_text_seen); 

 subSpinner.setText(spinnerSubs[position]);
 return mySpinner; }
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked well. I was wondering if you would interesting in taking a look at the next portion of my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819297/vm-shutting-down-after-loading-data-into-custom-text-spinner I'm having difficulty integrating into my Fragment.