# Trying to Set up TextSpinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to set up a simple text spinner that displays my products' sizes, but my VM keep shutting down. I've done a detailed break point analysis so please don't even go there. What are your thoughts on why this is not working?

```
11-20 01:07:23.333  11588-11588/com.app.store D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
```

I'll just post my entire Fragment. You'll notice I'm trying to feed a String[] array into the Adapter. I have one that is explicitly defined and one commented out which I'm pulling from another Class. Neither method works.

```
public class BuyFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);
        view = rootView;

        return rootView;
    }

    public int GetProductSizeCode() {
        return ((Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sizes)).getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    public void DisplayProduct(Product product) throws ParseException {

        String productName = product.getName();
        String productCost = "USD $" + product.getCost();
        String productDescription = product.getDescription();
        String careInstructions = product.getCareInstructions();

//        String [] productSizes = product.getSizes();
        String [] productSizes = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
        setUpSpinner(productSizes);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productTitle)).setText(productName);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productCost)).setText(productCost);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productDescription)).setText(productDescription);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.careInstructions)).setText(careInstructions);

        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.productImage)).setImageResource(product.getTemplateDrawableOverlay());

    }

    public void setUpSpinner(String[] productSizes) {
        Spinner spnr;
        spnr = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sizes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.custom_spinner,
                R.id.spinner_sizes,
                productSizes);
        spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

This is my custom spinner but you probably don't need that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/elgamigrey">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_main_seen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select your size"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Anybody have any idea what's going on? Despite anything else that might be going on, is the code at least correct?

**Update:**

I had the resource ID and the layout in the wrong order. It should have been like this when setting up the spinner:

```
 R.layout.custom_spinner,
 R.id.spinner_sizes,
```

Comment: You have not included all of your xml sheets.. one in particular, the custom_spinner.xml.

Comment: see `ArrayAdapter` constructor documentation: `textViewResourceId The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29), when you create your `ArrayAdapter`, the third parameter should be the id of the `TextView` where you want to render the `Spinner` content. Thus, looking at your XML layout, the id is `R.id.text_main_seen`, so the creation of your adapter should be something like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(),
    R.layout.custom_spinner,
    R.id.text_main_seen,
    productSizes);
```

Comment: Finally! Man lol. I really need to look at that documentation more closely.